# I cannot get the Python appJar TickOptionBox to function properly

Tags: python, user-interface

I will try to make this as brief as possible for potential help. I am trying to write some cool code for a pet project of mind, and it involves a GUI. I've been using appJar so far, and have had no issue calling new windows from an original one when I'm performing text entry. However, trying to make a list of check boxes has proven nearly impossible.

Here's some simplified code for what I'm trying to accomplish, but is not working:

```
from appJar import gui

def testfunction():
    def get(btn):
        print(app.getOptionBox("Favourite Pets"))
    petlist=["Dogs.txt", "Cats.txt", "Hamsters.txt", "Fish.txt"]
    print(petlist)
    app=gui()
    app.setFont(20)
    app.addTickOptionBox("Favourite Pets", petlist)
    app.addButton("GET", get)
    app.go()

testfunction()

def press(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
        app2.stop()
    else:
        testfunction()

app2=gui("Name")
app2.addButtons(["TEST", "Cancel"], press)
app2.go()
```

When I call the testfunction by itself, the output is as expected: a dictionary with {Dogs.txt: True, ...} with the True and False depending on whether or not you clicked the box in the menu.

However, if I attempt to call the function within the button press, every value in the dictionary is set to false, regardless of the checked boxes. This wouldn't be a huge deal normally, but I need the first setup to return an array with the values that are marked true (already done, except being able to return). What gives?

;tl-dr Appjar seems to not like nested sets of buttons and options, even when they work fine individually. HALP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to reproduce the issue you've mentioned

But something I would suggest - instead of creating multiple GUIs, have one GUI, and create a `SubWindow`:

```
from appJar import gui 
petlist=["Dogs.txt", "Cats.txt", "Hamsters.txt", "Fish.txt"]

def get(btn):
    print(app.getOptionBox("Favourite Pets"))

def press(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
        app.stop()
    else:
        app.showSubWindow("Pets")

app = gui("Name")
app.setFont(20)
app.addButtons(["TEST", "Cancel"], press)

app.startSubWindow("Pets")
app.addTickOptionBox("Favourite Pets", petlist)
app.addButton("GET", get)
app.stopSubWindow()

app.go()
```

This might make things easier to manage, and seems to give the desired results.